# regex that can end with string end, # or -

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the "FilterField1%3D[value]-FilterValue1%3D[value]" in the test strings below

```
FilterValue1%3DAT

    #InplviewHash988be455-e1fd-4d20-9eec-665972e3de21=FilterField1%3DRelatedMarket-FilterValue1%3D
    
    #InplviewHashb88353b1-3168-430b-89eb-010843e4b917=FilterField1%3DTrackingRef-FilterValue1%3D-FilterField2%3DAnotherRef-FilterValue2%3D-
    
    #InplviewHashb88353b1-3168-430b-89eb-010843e4b917=FilterField1%3DTrackingRef-FilterValue1%3D#InplviewHash988be455-e1fd-4d20-9eec-665972e3de21=FilterField1%3DRelatedMarket-FilterValue1%3DAT
```

The problem is that at the end it can end with the end of the string, a dash indicating another filter or a #. the hash and the dash I could capture but the end string makes the whole line match after the "Field.."

Here is the regex I could come up so far.

```
/FilterField1.+FilterValue1.*(#|)/gm
```

Regexer: https://regexr.com/5t1lk

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're exactly asking for. If you want the regex only to match exactly without any context, (e.g. `/hello/` would only match "hello" and not "ahelloooo"), you can use the `$` right before your ending slash and `^` right after your beginning slash.

Comment: It has to match the context because there can be a value after FilterValue1%3D[possibleValue] it can be empty it can have the value and right after have a # or a dash and that is where the regex fails.
Here is the regex in regexr

https://regexr.com/5t1lk

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, is [this](https://regexr.com/5t1lt) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that is it. Can you put it as answer? I will accept thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/FilterField1.+?FilterValue1[^-#\n]*/g
```

So, the lazy `.+?` - as opposed to the greedy `.+` - will stop at the next `FilterValue1` instead of the last of the line. Also, since we use `\n`, we must omit the multiline flag - useful only with start (`^`) or end (`$`) of line tokens in the expression.